# Animating a line to multiple points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using canvas, I'm trying to animate a single line that moves from one point to another, in succession.  (like the map in the Indiana Jones movies when he's flying from place to place).

I can't get my head around how to make this work.  My current code makes a filled triangle. Neat, but I want to see the vee shape draw itself.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/rbot/ERkCA/9/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ERkCA/12/)

Heres a quick method I put together. Its not perfect by any means. It uses rects, instead of lines, but could easily be changed to lines if you wanted to speed up how fast it draws (or just change the timeout methods update time). Just change the starting x/y to where you want it to start, and then pass an array of points to the function, and it will draw lines to each point continuing until it runs out.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasWindow");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var curPoint = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    index : 0   
}

var points = [{x:10, y:20}, {x:100, y:100}, {x:50, y:150}, {x:0,y:0}];
    
function toPoints(points){
    var targetPoint = points[curPoint.index];
    var tx = targetPoint.x - curPoint.x,
        ty = targetPoint.y - curPoint.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty),
        rad = Math.atan2(ty,tx),
        angle = rad/Math.PI * 180;;
     
        velX = (tx/dist)*1;
        velY = (ty/dist)*1;

    curPoint.x += velX;
    curPoint.y += velY;

    if(dist < 2){
        curPoint.index++;
    }

    c.fillRect(curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 1, 1);
    if(curPoint.index < points.length){
        setTimeout(function(){toPoints(points)}, 10);
    }
}

toPoints(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact goal but you may be missing  one or two `c.beginPath();` if you just want to draw lines and not fill the triangle.

(sorry, I don't know this movie...)